# Visual Studio 2012 SQL Server Object Explorer Script to File DateTime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2012

With Server Object Explorer in VS2012 I can script table data to file. The generated script for `datetime` create a string like this `N'2014-07-14 23:39:57'` and I have a problem to insert in database this format. Is there a why to specific a different format to script, for example like this `CAST(0x0000A3680186014C AS DateTime)`.

If no, I have a lot of generated query insert with that datetime format (`N'2014-07-14 23:39:57'`) and my database server give me conversation error. How I can globally set datetime format? I have already tried `set dateformat ydm` but it's not work.

Thank